# Navbar tabs with slick carousel

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

I'm creating *navigation bar tab*s using CSS, and in the tab I provide a slider (I use slick carousel). For some reason when the tab is active all the cards are aligned horizontally, but after I go to other tabs the card changes to vertical.

Does anyone know *why* this does happen?

[image]

[image]

```
<section>
            <style>
                .tabs-location {
                    border-bottom: 3px solid #951942;
                    padding-bottom: 1rem;
                }

                .tabs-location>li.active>a,
                .tabs-location>li.active>a:focus,
                .tabs-location>li.active>a:hover {
                    color: #fff;
                    background-color: #951942;
                }
            </style>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3 align='center'>Testing Location vOffice</h3>
                        <div class="container">
                            <ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified tabs-location" role="tablist" data-tabs="tabs">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#jakarta" data-toggle="tab">Jakarta</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tangerang" data-toggle="tab">Tangerang</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#bekasi" data-toggle="tab">Bekasi</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#surabaya" data-toggle="tab">Surabaya</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#bali" data-toggle="tab">Bali</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#medan" data-toggle="tab">Medan</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="jakarta">

                                    <div class="responsive-location">
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tangerang">

                                    <div class="responsive-location">
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="bekasi">Bekasi</div>
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="surabaya">Surabaya</div>
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="bali">Bali</div>
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="medan">Medan</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

for my js

```
<script>
        $('.responsive-location').slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: false,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 4,
            responsive: [{
                    breakpoint: 1024,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 3,
                        infinite: true,
                        dots: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 600,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 480,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    </script>
```

You can see the live code here
https://voffice.co.id/jakarta-virtual-office/index-dummy#testing

Comment: Difficult to help you without code.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Eg59hjL1